# CSS not loading after tampering URL

Tags: html, url, css, url-rewriting

I'm running my test site on localhost.
when i load it with URL: 
**localhost/projects/forums/index.php**

[image]

It looks like this (As Expected) 
But when

i give URL:
 **localhost/project/forums/index.php/**  ( / after index.php)

Css don't load.

[image]

looks like this.

Can anybody tell me how to tackle this? 
i have seen the same issue on many websites.

Comment: You should probably include php/html code snippet, which points how your CSS is included.

Comment: in index.php i'm including html file which contains link to CSS

Comment: If you include that snippet, then maybe others can help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Don't stick `/` on the end of the URL of the page
- Test the URL in your script and 301 redirect if it isn't the canonical URL you want to use
- For your links (including `<link>`s), use root relative URLs instead of current document relative URLs (i.e. start the URLs with a `/`)

I'd use all three myself.

Comment: ur 3rd option helped me. Ty